# Анимация линии кнопок

Tags: javascript, css, svg, css-animation

Мне нужно сделать анимационные линии при наведении на кнопку, от середины нижней линии. Линия должна идти в разные стороны и менять цвет. Примерно так должно работать, но оно начинается сверху.

```html
<section class="hero">
  <div class="svg-container">
    <a class="magic-link" href="#">
      <svg class="gradient" height="60" width="320" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <defs>
            <linearGradient id="gradient">
              <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#EB3349" />
              <stop offset="95%" stop-color="#EB3349" />
            </linearGradient>
          </defs>
          <rect class="rect-shape" height="60" width="320" />
          <div class="text">Hover me</div>
        </svg>
    </a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/47727807/7394871

Answer (score 4):

Посмотрите код, теперь линия идет по часовой стрелке.

Просто поиграйте со свойствами `.rect-shape` `stroke-dasharray` и `stroke-dashoffset`, чтобы получить эффект, который ваvм больше всего подойдет:

```
 stroke-dasharray: 140 620;
 stroke-dashoffset: 274;
```

И, конечно, вы можете поставить положительные или отрицательные значения `dashoffset`, тем самым меняя направление анимации.

Возьмите более подробные примеры здесь на официальных страницах:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dashoffset

```css
body {
  max-width: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  background: #EB3349;
}

a, a:hover, a:focus, a:active, a:visited {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.hero {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.svg-container {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 320px;
  max-height: 60px;
  cursor: default;
}

.rect-shape {
  stroke-dasharray: 130 620;
  stroke-dashoffset: 274;
  stroke-width: 8px;
  fill: url(#gradient);
  /* modify this with the color you want */
  stroke: #fff;
  transition: stroke-width 1s, stroke-dashoffset 1s, stroke-dasharray 1s;
}

.text {
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 32px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  color: #fff;
  top: -48px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.svg-container:hover .rect-shape {
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  stroke-dasharray: 760;
}

#gradient stop {
  transition: .5s all;
}

.svg-container:hover svg.gradient #gradient stop:first-child {
  stop-color: #EB3349;
}

.svg-container:hover svg.gradient #gradient stop:last-child {
  stop-color: #f45c43;
}
```

```html
<section class="hero">
  <div class="svg-container">
     <a class="magic-link" href="#">
        <svg class="gradient" height="60" width="320" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <defs>
            <linearGradient id="gradient">
              <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#EB3349" />
              <stop offset="95%" stop-color="#EB3349" />
            </linearGradient>
          </defs>
          <rect class="rect-shape" height="60" width="320" />
          <div class="text">Hover me</div>
        </svg>
     </a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Привет, Александр... Загляни в чат...